# How can I force Windows 7 to "Run As Administrator" for EVERY executable program?

Tags: windows-7

It seems like more often than not, I need to "Run As Administrator" in Windows 7.  Is there a way to force every program run as an administrator, without having to right click everything?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/83677/disabling-uac-on-windows-7

Comment: @Shane Madden -- not sure this is the same, disable User Authentication just means that the user will not be prompted for password, however programs should still run as a normal user, not Administrator

Comment: The correct question should be "How do I contact developers that can't write business applications that need local administrator privileges?"

Comment: MacGyver -- maybe you could also list which programs that requires you to "Run as Administrator" -- that should never be the case and probably something else is wrong.

Comment: @Soren Disabling UAC means that all processes running as a user in the `Administrators` group have a fully escalated state by default.  The right-click option stays in the context menu, but doesn't actually do anything.  You can confirm by disabling UAC then trying to launch a command prompt both ways - the non-"escalated" one has the tell-tale `Administrator: Command Prompt` in the title bar and the context of the "escalated" one stays in \users instead of moving to \windows\system32 like a normal escalation would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user in an administrator, disable User Account Control.
Else, switch to a user that is an administrator and disable User Account Control.